# Can we get a (generalized) metric from the notions of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$?

Tags: metric-spaces, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\leq)$ be an ordered set with countable infima and countable suprema. We can define $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in the obvious fashion and we say a sequence converges if they coincide.

So we get a notion of convergence and limit. This is backwards from the way one usually introduces limits.

> Under which reasonable circumstances can we now get (possibly a generalization of) a metric yielding the same notion of convergence and limits?

Comment: Are you familiar with metrization theorems in general topology?

Comment: @MoisheCohen No, but naming one would be enough. The bigger issue seems to be what kind of topology we need to define.

Comment: See for instance http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-02/S0002-9939-1969-0248761-1/S0002-9939-1969-0248761-1.pdf; http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56939/must-a-linearly-ordered-separable-space-be-metrizable

Comment: @MoisheCohen Looks promising. Though as I hinted wanting the entirety of a metric may be a bit restricting (would still be a proper answer, of course!). But I'm anyway left with the problem, that my ordering $\leq$ need not be total ($=$linear). -- I mean I don't want to restrict to total orderings if at all possible.

Comment: Oh, I see, then you will have even problem with Hausdorfness of the topology. Any reason you are interested in partial orders in this regard?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes. Examples: Measurable functions $E\to [0\,..\infty]$ for some measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ ordered in the obvious way; or measures $\mathcal E \to [0\,..\infty]$ ordered in (basically) the same way.

Comment: As I said not being Hausdorff (e.g.) is not a problem per se. Anything that has a reasonable notion of convergence will still do (a  pseudoquasimetric is still good enough e.g.).